# Where to find search term insert query in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How magento insert search term in to database. Where can i find insert query. Please mention the path of file that include the search term insert query.

Comment: what is your requirement for that?

Comment: @Jigar.Oza cloud you explain it briefly.

Comment: thanks, let me brief about my requirement. From website home page,user select category from the dropdown and not entering the search text and click search button. at that time i list all the product that are in that category but when i go to admin panel and check the search term, i am getting category id instead of category name. so which file and which code i have to update. please share your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Open **app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/SearchController.php**

and find:

```
public function saveAction()
```

Here you will find complete code to insert search terms.

Please let me know if I was able to answer your question.

Comment: great help. But let me explain my problem so you can help me in correct direction. sorry but i am new to magento. In Website home page i have category dropdown and search text box. now user select particular category from the dropdown and not entering any search value and go for search. i am able to load all product in that selected category. but in admin panel , in search term section i got id of that category instead of category. so if i want to store category name then where and which file i have to update. please share you idea

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for will vary slightly depending on the version of your Magento and on your settings. If you are using Magento CE 1.7.x. or higher and use typical settings (close to default) the insert of the search term and the actual results are saved together and the code can be seen in:

class:  **Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext**

file: **/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php**

method: `public function prepareResult($object, $queryText, $query)`

Look at lines 365-370:

```
    $sql = $adapter->insertFromSelect($select,
        $this->getTable('catalogsearch/result'),
        array(),
        Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INSERT_ON_DUPLICATE);
    $adapter->query($sql, $bind);
```